# How to handle multiple queries in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, subquery, psycopg2

I have data that requires a daily delsupsert to 10 PostgreSQL tables, called from Python's psycopg2. My current (single) query has 30 CTEs of inserts, updates, and deletes, that get executed only at the end as far as I know.

It's clean, but it's challenging to debug and complicated to understand. What's the best way to refactor this situation for code readability and easier debugging? (Stored procedures? Raise statements?)

Comment: Without knowing that these CTEs are doing a specific answer cannot be given. However, in general, you can break them down into individual statements (depending on how each CTE  is used in the others) in a procedure. The procedure establishes a [transaction](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-transactions.html) within which all statements will either succeed or fail as a unit.

Comment: Is a procedure able to give some debugging capabailities? I.e. if the transaction fails as a unit, can I know where exactly it went wrong?